# Serve 'artisan down' with 200 status code?

Tags: laravel, digital-ocean, laravel-artisan, digital-ocean-apps

Im currently using Digital Ocean App platform to host a Laravel app.

When i run `php artisan down` I get  a digital ocean error page from what i think is their load balancer saying the app couldn't be loaded. Which is being caused because the app is serving that page with a 503 status code.

Is it possible to serve `php artisan down` with a 200 status code so that my 503.blade template can be shown instead of the digital ocean page?

Answer (score 0):

There's no mention of it [in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/configuration#maintenance-mode), but running `artisan down --help` will give you your answer:

```
Description:
  Put the application into maintenance / demo mode

Usage:
  down [options]

Options:
      --redirect[=REDIRECT]  The path that users should be redirected to
      --render[=RENDER]      The view that should be prerendered for display during maintenance mode
      --retry[=RETRY]        The number of seconds after which the request may be retried
      --refresh[=REFRESH]    The number of seconds after which the browser may refresh
      --secret[=SECRET]      The secret phrase that may be used to bypass maintenance mode
      --status[=STATUS]      The status code that should be used when returning the maintenance mode response [default: "503"]
  -h, --help                 Display help for the given command. When no command is given display help for the list command
  -q, --quiet                Do not output any message
  -V, --version              Display this application version
      --ansi|--no-ansi       Force (or disable --no-ansi) ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction       Do not ask any interactive question
      --env[=ENV]            The environment the command should run under
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose       Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
```

So you want to do `artisan down --status=200`